# Make header position absolute

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I like the default back button for React Navigation's Stack navigator, but want it positioned absolutely, so the back button is overlayed in the screen and is side by side with "Text Two" .Right now, the back button is above "Text Two". How can I achieve this?

https://snack.expo.dev/@meg_hidey/lonely-chips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the header and add a [custom back button to go back to the previous screen](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating/#going-back).

Or you can keep the header and remove the back button and add a custom back button as described previously.

Comment: Damn :/ was really looking forward to not making my own header